# Invalid number of arguments Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, https, arguments

I try to activate the Https on my website but there is a problem when i try to launch Nginx ( before the bloc https everything working fine ) .

Error :

```
 nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "ssl_certificate" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/reverse-proxy.conf
```

My code :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

    location / {
                proxy_pass https://34.226.225.140:3000;
```

}}

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443;
    ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/certificateSSL/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/certificateSSL/private.key;
    server_name ***.fr;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;
    location / {
                proxy_pass https://**.***.***.***:****;
```

}}

Comment: Is this really the original config? Maybe you have some space in the path name in your real config?

Comment: yes is my original code ... there is no space in my code ..

Comment: The error message should specify a line number? Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the configuration across all included files, and ensure that Nginx is reading the correct file. Look for unmatched quotes or a missing `;` at the end of a line.